# Make On-hold order status notification working in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I need to send a customer email notification when I manually set order status from `processing` to `on-hold` status. I have added the following action hook into my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
```

Its not working (not showing in WP Mail Log), even though this particular email notification is enabled in woocommerce settings and the similar hook as shown below is working just fine:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
```

Environment:
Woocommerce v.3.5.1
Wordpress v.4.9.9
PHP 5.6

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated the hook**

You should try the following hooked function instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_on-hold', 'enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification', 10, 2 );
function enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification( $order_id, $order ){
    // Getting all WC_emails array objects
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Send the "On Hold" notification
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.

Comment: You probably meant `add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_on-hold', 'send_custom_status_email_notification', 10, 2 );` When i adjusted it, It worked! Thank you! Please fix your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm afraid there is little mistake again: `function enable_processing_to_on-hold_notification( $order_id, $order ){` will throw error `unexpected "-"` in function name;

Comment: @RWS Updated… Sorry ;)